# How to build a simple war file with sbt?

Tags: scala, web-applications, war, sbt

I'm trying to make a webapp using Scala and Apache Wicket and am not sure how to structure my project and use SBT to build a war file.  What directory structure should I use and how can I have SBT build the war file?

I'm new to SBT but my guess is there is an SBT plugin I need for this, but I'm not sure which to use.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Checkout the [web plugins](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/sbt-0.10-plugins-list). You'll probably want [xsbt-web-plugin](https://github.com/siasia/xsbt-web-plugin).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a blog post I did detailing the changes in SBT 0.10.x in regards to web projects: 
http://janxspirit.blogspot.com/2011/06/scalatra-mongodb-template-project-using.html

Most stuff is the same and the template project referenced in the post has been updated to 0.11.x Should help get you started with a simple web project with SBT. giter8 is a great tool for starting template projects.